# Emulating partial classes across assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to group together MANY helper classes into a common parent class for ease of use. For example, in my applications I want to do

```
Tools.StringTool.foo(..)
Tools.NumberTool.bar(..)
Tools.NetworkTool.something(...)
```

The idea here is to organize all the tools under a common Tools class so that intellisense can bring them all up when I type "Tools.".

Defining all the tools under a parent static partial class Tools works fine but not for Tools in a different assembly.

I tried to emulate static partial classes across assemblies by replacing the parent Tools class with a namespace X.Y.Tools, but for code written outside X.Y namespace, I need to fully qualify each tool before using it.

i.e.  in app code

```
  Tools.MyTool(..) // won't compile
  X.Y.Tools.MyTool(...) // will compile but ugly
```

Any suggestions how I can solve this issue or alternative approaches for organizing the tools?

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm misunderstanding the question. What is wrong with just defining the namespace "Tools" as opposed to the namespace "X.Y.Tools"?

Comment: I'm a little late to the question, but did you consider implementing the Facade pattern? ie MyUnionClass which exposes wrapper methods over the various assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the easiest way to do this is simply use namespaces

```
 // in project 1
 namespace Tools {
      public static class NetworkTool {
      }
 }

 // in project 2
 namespace Tools {
      public static class FileTool {
      }
 }

 // in client code (references both projects)
 Tools.NetworkTool.SomeMethod();
 Tools.FileTool.SomeMethod()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use extension methods in this case. All extension methods defined in classes within a namespace are made available when that namespace is imported.

This way you'd have static classes like `MyUtilityNamespace.MyClassInAssembly1` and `MyUtilityNamespace.MyClassInAssembly2` that all provide extension methods onto a single class instance, but this has ugliness associated with getting that class instance, like so:

```
// in central assembly
class Tool {
    private static Tool _t = new Tool();
    public static Tool T { get { return _t; } }
}
// in utility assembly 1
public static class MyExtensionClassInAssembly1 {
    public static void SomeUtilityMethodX(this Tool tool, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        // do something
    }
}
// in utility assembly 2
public static class MyExtensionClassInAssembly2 {
    public static void SomeUtilityMethodY(this Tool tool) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You'd use it like so:

```
Tool.T.SomeUtilityMethodX( Tool.T.SomeUtilityMethodY(), null );
```

it isn't pretty, but means you only need to import an namespace once, and the `Tool.T` is constant, there's no need to memorize `StringTool` or `NetworkTool`.

Another alternative is to use namespace or type aliasing, however this is laborious as you need to specify the `using Tools = X.Y.Tools.MyTool;` line on every source file you have.

Comment: I think what's needed to solve this is "static extension methods" which isn't available in .NET. For now, I'll just continue using parent partial static classes but have one for each assembly (i.e. CoreTools.Stringtool, CoreTools.NumberTool in Core.dll, NetTool.MimeTools, NetTool.SocketTool in Net.dll, etc).. I asked for suggestions and you did provide alternatives, so i've accepted your answer.